# How to optimize mysql query.?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, join, union

I have two tables with same structure.And both of these tables contain crores of records.For certian record generation i have to take both tables data.Sometimes there will be where condition in the query and sometimes there will not be any where condition because the where condition is build on the basis of user inputs given.So if there is no input given by the user then there will be no where clause and so the whole records will be fetched.and for this i am fetching both tables records and then union them.

Example tbl strucuture

### table_1

> column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4 | column_5

### table_2

> column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4 | column_5

So i am using the following query to get the results from the tables

```
select t1.* from table_1 as t1 inner join table_3 as t3 on t1.column = t3.column where condition
    union
select t2.* from table_2 as t2 inner join table_3 as t3 on t2.column = t3.column where condition
order by column
```

Note that the where condition may or may not be applied.Where table_3 contains a record details which is common in table_1 and table_2.I there an alternative to use something instead of union which improves the performace.?Like join.?

So my problem is that when i run this query without any where condition then its not executing since the tables contains crores of records.Also i need data from both tables.Any optimizing techniques is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What does `crores` mean?

Comment: 1 crore = 10 MILLIONS.

Comment: Are there duplicate rows in the two subqueries? Do you need to filter them out? If not, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Comment: Yes there may be.Thats why i am not using UNION ALL.But thats not the problem.performance is my problem

Comment: My point is that `UNION DISTINCT` is causing the performance problem. It has to go through all the results looking for duplicates to filter out, and that's slow when there are crores of results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use all or two or one of these options

1) try indexing on columns
2) set some default condition for WHERE clause
3) use limit.

and check your query with 'EXPLAIN' than you may be able to optimize your query
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html